# My friend said he swapped USDT to WBTC on Uniswap but this was the result, can someone explain what happened here please?

Tags: etherscan

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb124f98eff2955180b828bb5a81dff1c2b0dedff41d3bf102e6dcfa9940881fe

This is the link to transaction here.